# Cassandra is not starting with cassandra -f

Tags: windows, cassandra

I cannot start cassandra with 'cassandra -f' though my environment variables are correct. I'm using Windows 10 machine.

I'm getting the following error!

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cassandra -f
```

`*---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.                                                                                                                                                 It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra                                                                                                                                       for performance and stability reasons.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"                                                                                                          At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $p.Start() | Out-Null                                                                                                                                                                          +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                              + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                                                                                                            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."                                                                                                   At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:213 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $p.WaitForExit()                                                                                                                                                                               +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                                                                                                            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                                                                                                                At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:214 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()                                                                                                                                                         +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                             + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                                                                                                                At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:218 char:9                                                                                                                                                    +     if ($stderr.Contains("Error"))                                                                                                                                                                 +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                                                                                                                At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:231 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $sa = $stderr.Split("""")                                                                                                                                                                      +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                          + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Cannot index into a null array.                                                                                                                                                                      At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:232 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $env:JVM_VERSION = $sa[1]                                                                                                                                                                      +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                          + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                                                                                                                At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:234 char:9                                                                                                                                                    +     if ($stderr.Contains("OpenJDK"))                                                                                                                                                               +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Cannot index into a null array.                                                                                                                                                                      At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:247 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $pa = $sa[1].Split("_")                                                                                                                                                                        +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Cannot index into a null array.                                                                                                                                                                      At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:248 char:5                                                                                                                                                    +     $subVersion = $pa[1]                                                                                                                                                                           +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                               + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.                                                                                                                                       Performance of this node will suffer.                                                                                                                                                                Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              *---------------------------------------------------------------------*                                                                                                                              You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                                                                                                                At C:\cassandra\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:406 char:9                                                                                                                                                    +     if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1 -or [convert]::ToI ...                                                                                                                          +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"                                                                                                          At C:\cassandra\bin\cassandra.ps1:251 char:9                                                                                                                                                         +         $p.Start() | Out-Null                                                                                                                                                                      +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                          + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                                                                                                            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."                                                                                                   At C:\cassandra\bin\cassandra.ps1:253 char:9                                                                                                                                                         +         $p.WaitForExit()                                                                                                                                                                           +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                               + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                                                                                                            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Cassandra generally does not run on Windows. It did at one point have some Windows support, it hasn't been maintained. What version are you trying to start?

Comment: By the looks of it, it's failing when it tries to verify your JRE.  Do you have Java installed?  What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: @Aaron: I'm running JDK 12.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the line that it looks like it's failing on:

```
 if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1
```

When I'm on a CentOS (Linux) box, and I run `java -version`, I see the following output:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

As you can see, that version on that first line comes back in certain format "1.8.0_191."

So a couple of points about that:

1. I have no idea what the output of `java -version` shows for Java 12, but I do know that the format is different for some JDK vendors.  For example, the AdoptOpenJDK deployment causes issues with Cassandra 4.0 (as per this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14926).
2. Cassandra version 3 (and prior) only work with Java 8.  Cassandra 4 (not yet released) will support up to Java 11.  AFAIK, Java 12 isn't on the roadmap, yet.

For sure, I would install a lower version of Java.  If you're working with Cassandra 3, you should install the latest patch of Java 8.

If you continue to have problems, I would remove the Java version checks from the cassandra-env.ps1 file.  Although, you do so at your own peril.

Comment: java 12.0.1 2019-04-16                                                                                                                                                                             Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)                                                                                                                                                  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with Cassandra 3.11.7 on Windows 10, and resolved it by setting JAVA_HOME properly. I found that JAVA_HOME should point to the parent of 'bin', e.g. to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261" and not to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin". This has resolved the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Credit: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2274